# Disable cellphone network but keep wifi?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers, cellular-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable iPhone Cell Antennae](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48551/disable-iphone-cell-antennae)

Is there any way to make my iPhone 5 like a simple iPod touch? I'd like to disable all cellphone functionality but keep the wifi.

No jailbreak if possible.
I have an iPhone 5 running iOS 6.

Comment: @Gerry That is a general disable question - this one hones in on the iPhone 5 - no need to close this unless we can find an iPhone 5 version of the question that's already here as well.

Comment: This post does not seem redundant, because the author want to disable the cell phone but keep the wifi. For example, to be used in a trip without paying roaming. In this case I switch of cellular data, reboot the phone and do not enter the pin to keep the SIM locked. When I call my phone in this state I obtain a phone off message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can enable "Airplane Mode" and then turn on Wi-Fi.

For phones that use a GSM sim card (even if they are on CDMA networks), if you remove the SIM card, you disable the cellular radio. Calls and cellular data stop flowing in this case.

This will not disable phone calls, only internet:

Settings > General > Cellular > Cellular Data -> OFF

Comment: Of course i don't want to remove each time the SIM.. but your second solution is perfect if works :D

Comment: It will work. The only thing is it will turn off all antennas. Like da4 mentioned, you will need to re-enable wifi, but if you want bluetooth you will need to re-enable that.

Comment: @da4: disabling cellular data will not disable all cellphone network funcionality. Setting airplane mode and then turning on Wi-Fi is the way to go

Comment: @yes123 that was an edit to my post from someone else.

Comment: @da4: you can simply delete that part imo

Answer (score 2):

If you have a GSM version of the phone then you could just remove the SIM card. If you a CDMA version then you don't have a SIM card so you could turn on airplane mode and then turn WiFi on.

Comment: My CDMA iPhone 5 has a SIM card and pulling it disables things properly. I believe the 4S also had SIM cards even for CDMA models as well.

Comment: I thought for certain that CDMA phones don't have SIM cards. My bad if that is not the case